# Cannot rm corrupt directory

Tags: centos, rm, inode

CentOS6

I am logged in as root. It is a virtual machine running on a Windows 10 host in virtualbox as a vagrant machine.

I tried

`chmod -R 777 /home/thomas/WWW`

`chown -R root:root /home/thomas/WWW`

when trying to rm with `rm -rf /home/thomas/WWW` I get

> remove `/home/thomas/WWW/': Is a directory

which is weird

`ls -la` reveals a broken inode

> d??????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? WWW

but I have no idea how to fix it now.

Comment: Boot from a live image and run `fsck`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you filesystem is neither `/boot`, `/`, `/usr` or `/var` things are easy

- just comment your filesystem in /etc/fstab

  ```
  #/dev/vgdata/archives /home/archemar/tmp365 ext4 defaults       0       2
  ```
- reboot
- `fsck -t ext4 /dev/vgdata/archives` (fsck should recognize ext4 fstype)

else

1. locate you filesystem (df . ) will tell you

   ```
   /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1 ... /var
   ```
2. you are in volume group `vg1` and logical volume `lv1`
3. download an iso CD of same version of your OS (centos or redhat in this case).
4. use virtualbox to mount this iso and boot on it.
5. from boot menu, do not install, choose rescue mode.
6. locate your volume group, logical volume and filesystem, and do a fsck on it.